# Does smbj API support SMB v3.x dialect versions?

Tags: smbj

Exception is thrown while opening SMB connection using smbj API. It says: "SMB 3.x support is not yet implemented". The exception is thrown from "SMB2NegotiateRequest.putCapabilities(SMBBuffer buffer)" method.

Below is the code snippet that opens the connection. The ides is to establish connection with server which supports any of the mentioned dialect version.

```
    SMB2Dialect [] supportedSmdDialects = {
            SMB2Dialect.SMB_2_0_2,
            SMB2Dialect.SMB_2_1,
            SMB2Dialect.SMB_2XX,
            SMB2Dialect.SMB_3_0,
            SMB2Dialect.SMB_3_0_2,
            SMB2Dialect.SMB_3_1_1
    };
    SmbConfig cfg = SmbConfig.builder().
            withDialects(supportedSmdDialects).
            withMultiProtocolNegotiate(true).
            build();
    SMBClient client = new SMBClient(cfg);
    Connection conn = client.connect(host); // This line throws
```

In anything wrong with this code, or smb v3x is not implemented in fact?

Answer (score 0):

Currently indeed SMBv3 support is not implemented. To connect, remove the SMB3+ dialects from the array.

Comment: Hiery, thanks for your confirmation. Are there plans to add v3 support and if yes when is it expected to arrive?

Comment: The plans are there. You can follow the issues on Github.